# Why RestSharp doesn't parse the result to object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

Server side: Asp.Net Core MVC 2
Client 1 side: Core 2
Client 2 side: .Net Framework 4.6.2

Both clients use the same cs-file.

I see `response.Content` contains the valid response of server, but `response.Data` is `null` instead of `DbLibraryDto` instance.

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Client side:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:22170/DbLibrary/AddLibrary");
      var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
      request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

      var dto = new DbLibraryDto()
      {
        Id = null,
        Name = "Foo",
        RowVersion = new byte[] { },
        Companies = new List<DbDepartmentDto>(),
        Users = new List<DbUserDto>()
      };

      request.AddJsonBody(dto);

      var response = client.Execute<DbLibraryDto>(request);

      var content = response.Content; // {"id":"92924078-820f-401a-55c8-08d53d80728c","name":"Foo","companies":[],"users":[],"rowVersion":"AAAAAAAAB/I="}
      var obj = response.Data; // null
```

Controller code:

```
 [HttpPost("AddLibrary")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddLibrary([FromBody]DbLibraryDto dto)
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

      var obj = await _libraryService.AddLibrary(dto);
      if (obj != null) return Ok(obj);
      else return Forbid();
    }
```

[image]

**UPD**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThprServer.Dto.Common
{
  [Serializable]
  public class DbLibraryDto
  {
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DbDepartmentDto> Companies { get; set; } = new List<DbDepartmentDto>();
    public List<DbUserDto> Users { get; set; } = new List<DbUserDto>();
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: And response "Content-Type" is json also? What if you remove `RowVersion` property from `DbLibraryDto`?

Comment: Yes it is json too. I can solve the problem by such code row: `var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbLibraryDto>(response.Content);` but I expected to get the valid parsed object in the `response.Data` without Newtonsoft using.

Comment: But I need the `RowVersion` property.

Comment: Can you include definition of DbLibraryDto class?

Comment: I added *UPD* section.

Comment: On the server side my code read/write data to MS Sql Server via Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Well looks legit for me. I don't have time now to test that, but if I were you - I'd just replace default deserializer used by RestSharp with JSON.NET one. Your web api uses JSON.NET, so it's good to have the same serializer on both sides to not fall into issues like this one